# footnote in table with hyperlinks

Tags: tables, hyperref, footnotes

Answer to the problem below: 
I was using `latex c.tex; dvipdf c.dvi` to compile the pdf, instead I should use `pdflatex c.tex`, it also showed up that `\begin{savenotes}` will create links to the top of the page instead of the footnote, so instead of `\begin{savenotes}` and `\footnote` I should use `\tablefootnote`, credit to `@cgnieder`. Below the original question:

I'm trying achieve footnotes in tables that are hyperlinked (so that you
can click on the footnote marker to get to the footnote text. The following 
example enables me to add footnotes in tables:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}
\begin{savenotes}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
            A & 1 & 2 \footnote{This is the first footnote.} \\
            \hline
            B & 2 & 1 \\
            \hline
            C & 3\footnote{This is the second footnote.} & 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A table caption.}
        \end{table}%
    \end{savenotes}
Text\footnote{This footnote is hyperlinked.}
\end{document}
```

However the footnotes markers inside the table are *not* hyperlinked. Only the 
last one, outside the table is. Now, when I instead use

```
...
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnote}
...
```

That is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}
\begin{savenotes}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
            A & 1 & 2 \footnote{This is the first footnote.} \\
            \hline
            B & 2 & 1 \\
            \hline
            C & 3\footnote{This is the second footnote.} & 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A table caption.}
        \end{table}%
    \end{savenotes}
Text\footnote{This footnote is hyperlinked.}
\end{document}
```

I get closer, the footnote markers are not hyperlinked with a 
*underline*, however the hyperlink marker of the last footnote is hyperlinked 
with a *box*. 
I would like all footnote markers to be hyperlinked with a *box*. How 
can I achieve this?

Note that the question is not whether or not the footnote and footnote marker appear. I use `\begin{savenotes}` to do that. Rather the question is why the links are formatted as underscores and not boxes:

[image] or [image: Example2]

Comment: [`tablefootnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) can do this kind of thing...

Comment: I substituted `footnote` with `tablefootnote` but it is in fact the same output: The problem is not weather or not the footnote marker and footnote apears but rather how the links are build: Inside the table the link is only an underscore, outside the table it is a box. It is very difficult to click on only the underscore...

Comment: Funny! Your code runs with a warning and all the links are boxed for me. Please note that your code does not produce the table in your image (but something else). May be you have to give more details.

Comment: @Harish the links are boxed for me, too, but footnote one does not get hyperlinked (that's what the warning is about) and footnote two links to footnote one.

Comment: @cgnieder: I noticed it. But OP was worried a lot about getting the boxes. I think his latex system has something different than ours.

Comment: I use a Makefile to generate a pdf under linux: `latex c.tex; dvipdf c.dvi`, the result it c.pdf. c.tex is the above example. `latex --version` prints: `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2012/dev/Debian)`, dvipdf comes from the ghostscript package...

Comment: I'll try to switch to `TeX Live 2011` and Win32, if only I could get a link to a installer that I can use. Really, I dont really have an overview of all the different latex, pteTex, luatex, texmake, tex-package-managers, etc...

Comment: I'll try Windows/MikTeX

Comment: @Konrad I get the empty boxes, too, if I compile `latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf`. Maybe you should just try `pdflatex c.tex`?

Comment: @cgnieder Bingo ! Now the boxes appear. That was the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Konrad And now check the links. Add a second page so you can see if the pdf viewer makes the right jumps when you click on the links.

Comment: @cgnieder when I use `\begin{savenotes}` both `\footnote` and `\tablefootnote` only link to the beginning of the page, they don't jump directly to the footnote, only the last \tablefootnote in the table jumps to the (I think first) footnote defined in the table. Then I removed `\begin{savenotes}` and used `\tablefootnote` and then it seems to be the desired behaviour. So: `\begin{savenotes}` shouldnt be used but only `\tablefootnote` + `pdflatex` ...

Comment: Hmmm, I think I should have stayed with MS-WORD... :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we found out in the comments to the question if compiled with `pdflatex` the links are rectangles, i.e. the foodnote marks are inside the link boxes. `latex` + `dvips` leads to empty link boxes below the table footnotes instead.

The `savenotes` environment produces wrong hyperlinks, though. [`tablefootnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) gets them right:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
     A & 1 & 2 \tablefootnote{This is the first footnote.} \\
    \hline
     B & 2 & 1 \\
    \hline
     C & 3\tablefootnote{This is the second footnote.} & 3 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table caption.}
\end{table}%

Text\footnote{This footnote is hyperlinked.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your example but I still get the underscore version : http://i.stack.imgur.com/xggYv.jpg . I'm using a debian-wheezy installation with texlive-latex-extra package. It should be the latest setup... On a old slackware using `tablefootnote` was not possible...

Comment: Maybe I should switch OS, what OS and distribution do you use to get that the above output?

Comment: @Konrad I have TeX Live 2011 and compiled with `pdflatex`. The screenshot is taken from the view in `Okular` but it looks the same in `Acrobat Viewer`

Comment: Is it Win, Linux or MaxOSX? I guess the easiest way is maybe that I try it under Windows, which installer can I use for TeX Live 2011, is there some distribution that is most popular? I'm not that familiar with Tex...

Comment: @Konrad the OS (openSUSE 12.1) should really have nothing to do with it...

Comment: I'll try Windows/MikTeX...

Answer (score 4):

In case you're willing to consider using table notes instead of footnotes, the `referable` option of `threeparttablex` would provide a suitable command, `\tnotex`. While the package is originally designed to work with `longtable`, it also extends `threeparttable` environment by some commands, among them `\tnotex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]       
    \centering            
    \begin{threeparttable}  
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
            A & 1 & 2 \tnote{1} \\
            \hline
            B & 2 & 1 \\
            \hline
            C & 3\tnotex{tn:2} & 3 \\
            \hline
            Line & producing & space. \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[1] This is the first note.
            \item[2] \label{tn:2} This is the hyperlinked note.
        \end{tablenotes}      
    \end{threeparttable}
    \caption{A table caption.}
    \end{table}%    
Text\footnote{This footnote is hyperlinked.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your example but the output doesnt have any links. Only the footnote and footnote marker. My problem is that I dont get the right link: Inside the table it is only an underscore, outside the table it is a box... I want a box also inside the table.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what I get on compilation. Did you copy and compile the entire code?

Comment: The answer from _cgnieder_ indicates that I have some delta in the latex system I use. His setup outputs http://i.stack.imgur.com/5lpGN.png , my setup http://i.stack.imgur.com/xggYv.jpg ... what kind of setup do you use?

Comment: Yes, I compiled the entire code, but (on my system) when using your `\tnotex` I get a "3??" as output and no red link at all...

Comment: I suppose you did compile multiple times to allow the references to be updated? You could try if latex=>PS=>PDF works on your system. Should indeed your platform cause the issue, I can't provide any help since I'm mostly on Windows/MikTeX.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it with Windows/MikTeX then. Thanks. Note: I dont have enough reputation point to move the entries up/down, so thank you here...

Comment: You're welcome. You should be able to accept @cgnieder's answer as the solution, though.