# caption package not compatible with threeparttablex package?

Tags: captions, threeparttablex

I am trying to accomplish something like this:
[footnote in table with hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57149/footnote-in-table-with-hyperlinks#comment119988_57170)

Except using the caption package along with it, which I need for other things. The two approaches don't seem to mesh well together and I can't seem to figure out how to get around it. The warning I get is the following:

> Package caption Warning: `\label` without proper `\caption` on input line 32. 
>   See the caption package documentation for explanation.

And the references don't resolve (I get the dreaded ?? in their place). If I try to add a `\caption` prior to the `\label` for the `\tnotex` entries, it basically just tries to add multiple captions to the same table in my caption font.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

% This package allows for footnoting within tables
\usepackage{enumitem,booktabs,cfr-lm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}
\makeatletter
\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\tnote{\alph*}, ref=\alph*, itemsep=\z@, topsep=\z@skip, partopsep=\z@skip,parsep=\z@,itemindent=\z@,labelindent=\tabcolsep,labelsep=.2em,leftmargin=*,align=left,before={\footnotesize}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]       
    \centering            
    \begin{threeparttable}  
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
            A & 1 & 2 \tnote{1} \\
            \hline
            B & 2 & 1 \\
            \hline
            C & 3\tnotex{tn:2} & 3 \\
            \hline
            Line & producing & space. \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[1] This is the first note.
            \item[2] \label{tn:2} This is the hyperlinked note.
        \end{tablenotes}      
    \end{threeparttable}
    \caption{A table caption.}
\end{table}% 

\end{document}
```

It works fine without the caption package, but I use that for setting caption fonts and colors in my document. Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Just for fun (not at a pc so cannot test), what happens if you add a label after the caption? Is it even threeparttablex related? What happens if you remove threeparttable but keep the list you've made? My guess is the same error. I guess it is the caption vs label noob test (common first time user error of not placing the label after the caption)

Comment: @cfr I know about why the op changed the list, just wanted to rule out that the problem should stem from threeparttablex

Comment: @daleif It isn't clear the OP knows why the list was changed, actually. That code is intended to automate the numbering of the table notes which makes no sense if you are going to say `\item[1]`.

Comment: @cfr not at all, I just hadn't had the opportunity to test my theory ;-)

Comment: No, it does not work fine without the caption package. You get an empty reference instead of the desired "2". See my answer below.

Comment: @daleif Consider it disconfirmed in light of later testing, controlling for factors which probably mistakenly suggested success initially. Cleaned up to remove my erroneous comments. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package **threeparttablex** loads **threeparttable** and can certainly be used, as is clear from other answers, including the one linked from the question, to customise the standard `tablenotes` environment for use with `tabular` etc. and is not limited to use with `longtable` as suggested in another answer.

In fact, the code you have works fine for me with only a couple of minor changes.  You are redefining `tablenotes` to enable *automatic* enumeration but then overriding that with hard-coded labels. This doesn't make sense. If you want the non-recommended-not-best-practice Arabic numerals as markers, just change the customisation of `tablenotes` appropriately.

```
\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\tnote{\arabic*}, ref=\arabic*, itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt ,parsep=0pt, itemindent=0pt, labelindent=\tabcolsep, labelsep=.2em, leftmargin=*, align=left, before={\footnotesize}}
```

and then write

```
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item This is the first note.
      \item \label{tn:2} This is the hyperlinked note.
    \end{tablenotes}
```

If you prefer to write `\item[1]` etc., then don't redefine the `tablenotes` environment in the first place.

With these changes and the addition of `\usepackage{hyperref}`, the hyperlinked note works fine for me:

[image: hyperlinked tablenote]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,cfr-lm}% you aren't using booktabs
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\tnote{\arabic*}, ref=\arabic*, itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt ,parsep=0pt, itemindent=0pt, labelindent=\tabcolsep, labelsep=.2em, leftmargin=*, align=left, before={\footnotesize}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
      \hline
      A & 1 & 2 \tnote{1} \\
      \hline
      B & 2 & 1 \\
      \hline
      C & 3\tnotex{tn:2} & 3 \\
      \hline
      Line & producing & space. \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item This is the first note.
      \item \label{tn:2} This is the hyperlinked note.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \caption{A table caption.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: I've found out my error. I had a `misplaced\noalign` message which made me think it could only work with longtable or latblex. Actually the problem was only where to put the `caption`command, which differs in both cases. I must say  the documentation is not very clear to me…

Comment: @Bernard To be fair, I am pretty sure I relied partly on the source code when I did this (without hyperref in my case, but that turns out to not matter).  I probably overreacted to the suggestion that the OP was just plain confused when I knew that I was using something very, very like it perfectly successfully. (And recently - I knew I'd read this stuff within the past three or four months.) And the linked answer does make the point right off that `threeparttablex` can extend `threeparttable`'s functionality using `referable`.

Comment: And also `\setTableNotesFont`. Well, I've learnt something! Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: @Bernard I think there should be a badge for knowing something you didn't about typesetting tables!

Comment: What I don't understand is why the author didn't go ahead and make the enumeration of the notes automatic. I assumed this was because it was just impractical or impossible, but it turned out to be quite easy.

Comment: Perhaps because it makes no natural sense: in a table there is no linear order, as it is a two-dimensional object.

Comment: I meant automatically number them in the `tablenotes` environment. It is a list anyway. Making it an ordered list works fine. Then the notes in the table use the labels you set in the list of notes and, if you add a note to the list, you just insert it appropriately and the numbers are updated. It isn't a huge deal to hard-code them - it just seemed an odd thing to do.

Comment: Ah! I saw that differently. Numbering from some order on the cells of the table; I think it would be tricky, as there are several possibilities to define a total order.

Comment: That would, indeed, be tricky ;).

Comment: @cfr, to answer your question about why the author was not making the enumeration of the notes automatic, I was recycling a piece of code that I obviously did not fully understand. Your answer has fully cleared this up for me, and now it is all making a lot more sense.

Comment: @R.K.G. I actually meant the author of `threeparttablex` ;).

Comment: @cfr When using your code the extra \label{tab:mytable} isn't necessary, the caption package won't drop a warning without it. (So no, this has not eliminating the warning. Changing `\item[2]` to `\item` has eliminated the warning instead.)

Comment: @cfr This sounds strange to me since adding a `\label` to the caption shouldn't make any difference. And I just tried it out, I took the original example code and added a `\label` after `\caption`, but the warning about the other `\label` still occurred. But: For compatibility reasons the warning will not be typeout immediately but triggered from inside of the aux file. Therefore you need to compile twice to see the warning when starting without aux file. Maybe this has happened to you, and therefore you misleadingly thought that the warning has gone?!?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt That's very possible, yes.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks for your patience in making this point. I checked and I'm sure you're right about why I thought it (as well as its not being true). I've edited accordingly. And removed my erroneous comment.

Comment: @cfr No problem! I just wanted to get sure I haven't overseen an issue within my `caption` package since you made me still a little bit in doubt. But if you can't reproduce this either I can close this issue in my head, too. Thanks for investigating!

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt No, you're absolutely right. I can reproduce what I likely did. I may well have cleaned the generated files and thought the `\label` made the difference for that reason. By my next compilation, I would have made other changes which really did get rid of the warning and would just have checked that it still failed to appear. Sometimes TeX experimentation is complicated!

Answer (score 7):

First of all, this is *not* an incompatibility between `caption` and `threeparttablex` package. The `caption` package only gives a hint that something is going wrong here, and it's correct about this.

But lets first start with the default implementation of `\item`, offered by LaTeX2e itself:

```
\def\@item[#1]{%
  ...
  \if@noitemarg
    \@noitemargfalse
    \if@nmbrlist
      \refstepcounter\@listctr
    \fi
  \fi
  ...}
```

As one can see here, `\item` will only produce a reference (which can be used by `\ļabel` later on) if the list is numbered and `\item` was used without optional argument. So especially `\item[2]` will *not* generate a reference which can be used by `\label` and `\ref`. (This seems to be a design decision made by Leslie Lamport.)

Example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ref{item1} \ref{item2}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{item1} Text
\item[2] \label{item2} Text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Both `\ref` will output `1` here (and not `1` and `2`) because only the `\item` without optional argument is generating a reference, so both `\label` are actually using the same reference created by the `\item` without optional argument.

The `threeparttablex` package redefines `\item` (inside `tablenotes` only), so `\item[2]` will produce a reference (by defining `\@currentlabel`): [1]

```
\renewcommand\tablenotes{%
  \let\TPTL@item=\item
  \renewcommand\item[1][]{\TPTL@item[##1]%
    \phantomsection\protected@edef\@currentlabel{##1}}
  ...}
```

Example document:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
            A & 1 & 2 \tnote{1} \\
            \hline
            B & 2 & 1 \\
            \hline
            C & 3 \tnotex{tn:2} & 3 \\
            \hline
            Line & producing & space. \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[1] This is the first note.
            \item[2] \label{tn:2} This is the hyperlinked note.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \caption{A table caption.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The outcome is fine, and `\tnotex{tn:2}` will produce a `2` as expected. (Note: One can add the usage of the `caption` package here without problems.)

Now we will add the usage of `\renewlist{tablenotes}` offered by the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
            A & 1 & 2 \tnote{1} \\
            \hline
            B & 2 & 1 \\
            \hline
            C & 3 \tnotex{tn:2} & 3 \\
            \hline
            Line & producing & space. \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[1] This is the first note.
            \item[2] \label{tn:2} This is the hyperlinked note.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \caption{A table caption.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Upps, the `2` is gone now. What has happened?

Well, the `\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}` re-defines the `tablenotes` environment to use an ordinary `enumerate` environment instead. And as we know from above `\item[2]` inside an ordinary `enumerate` environment will not generate a reference for usage with `\label` at all, so this eliminats the feature offered by `threeparttablex` that `\item[xxx]` actually will generate a reference. So `\label{tn:2}` will now pick the reference instead generated by the last command which has generated one. But there isn't any, so the output is simply empty. Adding a `\section` demonstrates this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}  % <= This line added

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
            A & 1 & 2 \tnote{1} \\
            \hline
            B & 2 & 1 \\
            \hline
            C & 3 \tnotex{tn:2} & 3 \\
            \hline
            Line & producing & space. \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[1] This is the first note.
            \item[2] \label{tn:2} This is the hyperlinked note.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \caption{A table caption.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Now `\tnotex{tn:2}` will produce a `1` (instead of the expected `2`) because `\label{tn:2}` (still) does not point to the `\item[2]` but to the (first) section instead.

But why does the example document offered by cfr gives the correct output? Because it uses `\item` without optional argument, and as we know from above this will always produce proper references.

Now the last part of the story: What does the `caption` package has to do with all of this?

Well, the `caption` package has a feature which detects `\label` without proper reference within `figure`, `table`, `threeparttable` etc. And since this is exactly the problem here this feature will strike.

BUT: I confess that the content of the warning message offered by the `caption` package is misleading here. I choose the text "\label without proper \caption" since a `\label` without a leading `\caption` is usually the problem here. I will change it to the more technically correct text "\label without a proper reference" in the next version.

[1] This is a documented feature of the `threeparttablex` package: "By using the package option »referable« we will change a few threeparttable internals such that (a) The manually specified note markers issued by \item[...] is referable, and ..." (Taken from the `threeparttablex` documentation, as of May 22, 2014)

Comment: Great explanation! However, it is not really an incompatibility between the two packages but between certain uses of them. In truth, the only reason I redefined `tablenotes` in terms of an `enumitem` list in the first place was to automate the numbering of the `\item`s within the list. If you are going to hard-code those labels anyway, then there isn't much reason to use `enumitem` to redefine `tablenotes` at all. At least, that's my way of thinking about it.... So it is fine to use these 2 packages together provided you either (1) don't use `enumitem` here or (2) automate `tablenotes`.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the feedback! Yes, you are right about the "incompatibility", so I just dropped that part of the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

My workaround is probably not exactly what you were looking for, but for tables with footnotes, I think it is a good solution to use a `tabularx` environment and put the footnote in a final `p`-column with the width of the table specified.  I also recommend inline enumerations as footnote to use the full width of table.  Macro `\tabref` is used to customize the appearance of the references.  Putting it together:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs,cfr-lm,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption,hyperref}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top,aboveskip=6pt}

\newcommand*{\tabref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \captionbox{A table caption made somewhat longer to see the
    effect\label{tab:example}}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{@{}c>{\hfil}X<{\hfil}c@{}}
      \toprule
      Line & producing & space \\
      \midrule
      A & 1 & 2\tabref{tn:1} \\
      B & 2 & 1 \\
      C & 3\tabref{tn:2} & 3 \\
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}}{\RaggedRight
        \begin{enumerate*}
        \item  This is the first note.\label{tn:1}
        \item  This is the hyperlinked note\label{tn:2}.
        \end{enumerate*}%
      }%
    \end{tabularx}%
  }%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]